# VirtualChannelInit stucks

Tags: c++, windows, rdp, virtual-channel

I'm developing an rdp virtual channel application. I've registered client side dll in registry and trying to understand, that client dll is loaded.
But I'm getting stuck when calling `pVirtualChannelInit` from `pEntryPoints`.
It just doesn't return any result, debugger goes to disassemled code on this function. But if do not stop on this call, `VirtualChannelEntry` called for the second time (why?).

If I use debugger to mstsc.exe.
After some time after first call, in console I can see this:
`First-chance exception at 0x00000004 in mstsc.exe: 0xC0000005: an access violation in the performance at 0x00000004.` //translated with google
And after second call when rdp session is appearing on the screen:

```
First-chance exception at 0x773EC42D (KernelBase.dll) in mstsc.exe: 0x000006BA: RPC server is unavailable.
First-chance exception at 0x773EC42D (KernelBase.dll) in mstsc.exe: 0x000006BA: RPC server is unavailable.
First-chance exception at 0x773EC42D (KernelBase.dll) in mstsc.exe: 0x000006BA: RPC server is unavailable.
First-chance exception at 0x773EC42D in mstsc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x06CCF8C0.
First-chance exception at 0x773EC42D in mstsc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x06CCF8C0.
First-chance exception at 0x773EC42D in mstsc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x773EC42D in mstsc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x773EC42D in mstsc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x06CCF8C0.
First-chance exception at 0x773EC42D in mstsc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x06CCF8C0.
First-chance exception at 0x773EC42D in mstsc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x773EC42D in mstsc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
```

Pointers in pEntryPoints are always:

`pVirtualChannelInit - 0x00000004
pVirtualChannelOpen - 0x0000ffff
pVirtualChannelClose - 0x000000b8
pVirtualChannelWrite - 0x00000000 (Why 0?)`

```
HANDLE ClientHandle = NULL;
CHANNEL_DEF pChannel[1];
CHANNEL_ENTRY_POINTS SavedEntryPoints;
PCHANNEL_INIT_EVENT_FN pChannelInitEventProc;

BOOL VCAPITYPE VirtualChannelEntry(PCHANNEL_ENTRY_POINTS  pEntryPoints)
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("D:\\Projects\\bench_cli\\ConsoleApplication1\\Release\\example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";

    UINT retval1 = 0;
    ZeroMemory(&pChannel[0], sizeof(CHANNEL_DEF));
    strcpy(pChannel[0].name, "Bench");
    pChannel[0].options = CHANNEL_OPTION_ENCRYPT_RDP | CHANNEL_OPTION_COMPRESS_RDP;
    pChannelInitEventProc = VirtualChannelInitEvent;
    memcpy(&SavedEntryPoints, pEntryPoints, sizeof(CHANNEL_ENTRY_POINTS));

    myfile << " copied" << endl;

    // call VirtualChannelInit using the function pointer in
    // PCHANNEL_ENTRY_POINTS
    myfile << "Initing" << endl;

    retval1 = pEntryPoints->pVirtualChannelInit (&ClientHandle,
                pChannel, 1, VIRTUAL_CHANNEL_VERSION_WIN2000,
                pChannelInitEventProc); //here we stuck

    myfile << " init" << endl; //this never printed
    myfile.close();

    return TRUE;
}

VOID VCAPITYPE VirtualChannelInitEvent( LPVOID pInitHandle, UINT event, LPVOID pData, UINT dataLength)
{
...//never called
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'll check it asap.

Comment: Any news? I am currently doing virtual channel stuff, I can help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pVirtualChannelInit` should be a valid pointer (to code). `0x00000004` is not, hence the `access violation`

Your problem may be caused by improper structure packing/alignment at compile time.

Use a debugger to figure out the correct alignment, by inspecting the memory pointed to by the `PCHANNEL_ENTRY_POINTS pEntryPoints` parameter passed to your `VirtualChannelEntry` implementation. The structure starts with 2 **32 bits** values, followed by 4 function pointers. The first field is a size field (value depends on bitness, 32 bits:0x0018, or 64:0x0028), the second one should be 0x00001.

Then, use `#pragma pack push/pop` (MSVC compiler) around the inclusion of the header defining the `CHANNEL_ENTRY_POINTS` structure to force the correct alignment at compile time.

Comment: Thank you so much, `#pragma pack` around Cchannel.h solved it.

Comment: @Dimson You'r welcome. If you have other questions, ping me with a comment here. Happy programming!